# How to update the checkboxs dynamically in custom preference center page using AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, update, landing-page, custom-profile

I have created one data extension using these fields 'name, email, checkbox1,checkbox2'. Also i created one custom profile center page like landing page using lookupRows function. My requirement is when we click the user registration link, it will be redirect to custom preference center page which have 3 checkboxes . So my doubt is how to update the checkboxes in that page dynamically. Can anybody please give me any suggest me.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to make dynamic? Do you want the label to change, the # of checkboxes showing to change, the input type to change, etc..

Comment: @Jason Hanshaw, For example i got one email. The email consists url (after user registration sending verified url send to user email), When i click that link, It will be need to go to custom preference page, which is need to developed by us. So, here i update the data using checkboxes then the data also need to update the data extension.

Answer (score 0):

1. It Depends on your data source (SFDC object or DX) but in general => query the source and given one of the fields is boolean (in this case) you can proceed to step two
2. Check or uncheck the checkbox based on a field value (below you can find HTML paired with AMPScript)

   < input type="checkbox" %%[If @fieldFromDataExtension=="true" Then]%% 
   checked="checked"
   %%[EndIf]%% name="AnyNameYouLike" >